# Element not visible, Element not interactable, SeleniumBasic

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to log into a site.

The problem is, to login, you need click on a login button which takes you to login form inside the same page (without loading new one), and then you enter credentials.

I clicked on the button successfully, however there seems to be a problem with username and password. This is the html for username part.

When I do:

1. .FindElementById("username").Click, it says ElementNotVisibleError and under it element not interactable
2. .FindElementById("username").SendKeys "my username", it says element not interactable only.

Please help me solve this problem, it would take a lot of load off me.

Comment: Select the username field, right-click and select inspect. Post an image with this info and with the password field as well.

Comment: Please share the URL if possible else HTML of the page.